# How to limit sort() to one list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
>>> AB
['1', '3', '1', '3']
>>> BC = AB
>>> BC
['1', '3', '1', '3']
>>> BC.sort()
>>> BC
['1', '1', '3', '3']
>>> AB
['1', '1', '3', '3']
```

I wanted to sort only list BC. Why it sorted list AB as well and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically pointing to the same area in the program's memory with AB and with BC. So, to create BC as a new list, and save it in a different place in the memory, you can do this:

Assuming this is python:

```
BC = AB[:]  # creates a copy of AB
```

Now, when you modify BC, it will not change AB. Sorting will have no affect on AB this way. Now they point to different places in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that BC and AB are **pointing** to the **same object** in memory and variable holder AB and BC act like a **pointer**. They both are **pointing** to the same thing and so if you sort BC, the list BC is **pointing** to gets sorted and AB also points to the **now sorted** list BC.

To correct this, instead of saying `BC = AB` you can say `BC = AB[:]` which will store a **copy** of AB in BC instead of AB itself. This will result in: changes made to one **not** being reflected in the other.